# Pass github action environmental variables to python

Tags: python-3.x, post, github-actions, circleci, secret-key

On my CircleCI's config.yml file, someone wrote a shell post (ie):

```
curl -X POST -H 'Header: header' \
  --url https://website/${{secrets.SECRET_TOKEN}} \
  --data '{"text": "Hello ${{ github.actor }}"}'
```

I have to replicate the same behavior using python and requests (this file will be executed by CI).
I don't understand how to handle those variables--because they are not CI's env vars, instead they are github action environmental variables.

```
url = "https://website/${secrets.ROBBY_SLACK_ALERT_TOKEN_CODE_REVIEWS}"
data = {"text": Hello ${github_actor}
f = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

note: I left the header out in the example above.

I could pass the github var to a ci var, and then retrieve it with python--but not sure the proper syntax to use in the config.yml (ie):

```
 - env: ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME: ${{ secrets.SECRET_TOKEN }}
```

Any help would be welcome.

Thx

Comment: Is this about github actions or circle ci?

Answer (score 0):

The last option would be fine, some are defined for every workflow run, see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) for the list.

These are automatically populated by GitHub during every run.

After that you can read them in a standard python way:

```
import os

actor = os.environ[”GITHUB_ACTOR”]
```